# Slideshows will not start on load

Tags: javascript, slideshow, onload

I got some help earlier on running multiple slide shows on one page, my problem now is getting the slide shows to work/start on the page.

HTML:

```
<p align="center"><font size="2"><b>Companies Supporting<br />R&M Research:</b><br  />         (click logo for company info)</font></p>
        <p align="center"><a href="#" target="_blank"><IMG SRC="./images/schlumberger.gif" WIDTH="180" HIGHT="200" BORDER="0" NAME="bannerad1"></a>
</p>
       <br />

            <hr noshade="noshade" size="0" color="#4c617e" />
 <br />

        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b>Thank you to the following for<br />their MARCON '12 support</b><br />(click logo for company info)</font></p>
        <p align="center"><a href="#" target="_blank"><IMG SRC="./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg" WIDTH="180" HIGHT="200" BORDER="0"   NAME="bannerad2"></a>
       <br />

 <br />

        <p align="center"><a href="#" target="_blank"><IMG SRC="./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg" WIDTH="180" HIGHT="200" BORDER="0"   NAME="bannerad3"></a>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideShow = function(imagesArray, hrefsArray, bannerad) {

var counter = -1, timer = null;

function banner() {
    counter++;
    if (counter > imagesArray.length-1) { counter = 0; }
    bannerad.src = imagesArray[counter];
    bannerad.parentNode.href = hrefsArray[counter];
}
timer = setInterval(banner, 6000);

};


var ads1 = [
    "./images/okuma.jpg",
    "./images/schlumberger.gif",
    "./images/uesystems_logo.jpg",
    "./images/brady.jpg",
    "./images/ats.png"
    ];


var newplace1 = [
    "http://www.okuma.com/home.html",
    "http://www.slb.com/",
    "http://www.uesystems.com/",
    "http://www.bradyid.com/bradyid/cms/contentView.do/6974/Visual-Workplace.html",
    "http://www.advancedtech.com/"
    ];


var ads2 = [
    "./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/brunson_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/ctc_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/descase_logo.jpg"
    ];


var newplace2 = [
    "http://www.globalreliability.com/home",
    "http://www.brunson.us",
    "http://www.ctconline.com/_home.aspx",
    "http://www.des-case.com"
    ];

var ads3 = [
    "./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/brunson_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/ctc_logo.jpg",
    "./marcon/images/descase_logo.jpg"
    ];


var newplace3 = [
    "http://www.globalreliability.com/home",
    "http://www.brunson.us",
    "http://www.ctconline.com/_home.aspx",
    "http://www.des-case.com"
    ];


slideShow(ads1, newplace1, document.bannerad1);
slideShow(ads2, newplace2, document.bannerad2);
slideShow(ads3, newplace3, document.bannerad3);

</script>
```

I tried using:

```
<body onload="banner();">
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=function() {
  slideShow(ads1, newplace1, document.bannerad1);
  slideShow(ads2, newplace2, document.bannerad2);
  slideShow(ads3, newplace3, document.bannerad3);
}
```

Comment: I added "window.onload=function(){}" and it still will not work. The link to the site is http://www.rmc.utk.edu/. I am using the exact same code that is displayed up top, any ideas?

Comment: Remove the onload from the body tag and look in the console. You have an error

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so I'll put this in an answer...

mplungjan's answer works fine for me (just tested with your code), but you will have to remove the `<body onload="banner();">` or JS runs into an error.

`banner()` is a local function in your slideShow "class", which is not visible from outside. Besides, it doesn't need to be called, `setInterval()` does it for you. ;)

Comment: Aletheios i did make sure to remove the <body onload="banner();"> so what your saying is with the code above with no modification other then mplungjan's it should work?! I guess something is overlapping somewhere

Comment: Yes, I used your code from above, added mplungjan's workaround instead of your slideshow initialization and it worked (Firefox, Opera). Of course I had to replace the image paths in order to test with my own images (make sure your image paths are correct ^^).